# how to export and import MySQL schema in a single file by DataGrip IDE

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I am new in [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)  IDE .
how to do this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done from the Context menu → Dump with...

[image]

Comment: it is avilabe there